# How to access a map value with an index index in Hugo?

Tags: hugo

I have the following yaml template : `consultant.yaml`

```
title: myTitle    
content: myContent  
cards:
  - card:
      title: Title 1 
      args:
        arg1: "blablabla 1"
        arg2: "blablabla 2"
   - card:
      title: Title
      args:
        arg1: "blablabla 3"
        arg2: "blablabla 4"
        arg3: "blablabla 5"
```

I want to display each arg[x] of my card element using an index and not the key itself. I read about the `index` function and it seems to be possible.

```
Hugo doc : 
Soluton 1 : index COLLECTION INDEX
Solution 2 : index COLLECTION KEY
```

I want to use `Solution 1`.

I have the following HTML template : `single.html`

```
  {{ range .Site.Data.consultant.consultant.cards }}
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="">
      <div class="">
        <h3 class=""> {{.title}} </h3>
      </div>

      <p>{{.args}}</p>
      <p>{{ (index .args).arg1}}</p>
      <p>{{ (index .args). 0}}</p>

  </div>
</div>
{{end}}
```

- the first `p` element display a map `map[arg1:blablabla 1 arg2:blablabla 2]` => OK
- the second `p` element display the first value `blablabla 1` => OK
- the third `p` element display a map `map[arg1:blablabla arg2:blablabla 2]` => KO.

The third `p`should display the first element just like the second one and I don't get why.

Comment: Do you have control over the content/format of the input yaml? If so, just use an array in the yaml, which should convert to a Go slice.

Comment: Indeed `index Collection index` only work with an array but NOT a map.

Doing the following works :

`$var := .Site.Data.consultant`
`index $var .cards 0`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was solved over on the *Hugo* forums:

https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-to-access-a-map-value-at-an-index-with-the-index-function/13330

```
<ul>
{{ range $test.cards }}
  <li>{{.card.title}}
    <ul>
      {{range $key, $value := .card.args}}
      <li>{{$key}}: {{$value}}</li>
      {{end}}
    </ul>
  </li>
{{ end }}
</ul>
```